Inner Underlay not working in Distance Field shader of TextMeshPro
i have try different settings combination to make working Inner Underlay for my text, but no results at the final. I am adding to the post images with the settings of my text, as well as a shader with independent settings and the final rendering of the images:
Inspector Settings
Inspector Settings
Inspector Settings
Inspector Settings
Result
